# Best convention for cross-class helper function

Tags: c++

Lets say I have two classes, Class A and Class B, both defined in namespace NAMESPACE. Both of these classes utilize a helper function, helper(). Since both classes use this function, I figured it would be ok to define the helper() in the .h file in the same namespace but outside both classes. However, then the function is visible and usable to whoever uses my code. My understanding is that this goes against convention and instead this function should be private by some mechanism, since I never want this function to be explicitly called. However, to declare it private would require that I declare it in both classes and thus define it twice later in the .cpp file. What would be the best way to create a function usable by two classes but invisible to a user?

Comment: C++ access control (`public`, `private` etc) only applies to class members, so what language feature could you use for two different classes to both have the same function as a member?

Comment: @PaulRenton, how would that help?  A friend could access `A` and `B`'s private members, but that's not what's wanted. The friend would be accessible to all users, but that's not what's wanted.

Comment: You are correct I misunderstood his question. Removing the comment.

Answer (score 4):

One common approach would be to place the function into a `detail` namespace within your namespace. This doesn't mean other people can't intentionally use it, but it doesn't pollute your API's namespace.

Alternately if you implement both classes in the same source file just put it in an anonymous namespace in that source file and don't have it in a header at all.

Answer (score 1):

```
struct CommonImpl {
protected:
  static void foo() { }
};

struct A : CommonImpl {
  void bar() { CommonImpl::foo(); }
};

struct B : CommonImpl {
  void bar() { CommonImpl::foo(); }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

How about creating a separate class with the helper functions declared as static private functions. In the class declaration you also declare the classes that will use these helper functions as friend classes. This way the functions are visible to the classes that need them and no one else.

Comment: That's inflexible, the separate class would have to know every possible user of it in advance and declare each of them as a friend. Instead make the function in the new class `protected` and make `A` and `B` inherit from it, that way only derived classes can use the function.